# How to change ext4 Hard drive partion to NTFS for installing Windows xp?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a ubuntu in Root directory with separated Home directory. This is all my hard partition. I inserted xp cd to install it but I can't find any hard drive suggestion ! I decided to boot it by Gparted and change the Root directory to NTFS, I formatted it and run xp cd again. I can't find any hard drive too. I don't want to change all partitions because I don't want to lose my data on them. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Gparted
2. Select the Linux partition
3. Right click it and select Resize/Move
4. Change its size to make room for the Windows partition.
5. Right click anywhere and select New.
6. Fill up the free space with the new partition and format it as NFTS.
7. Profit!

After installing Windows XP, be sure to run boot-repair from a live CD to get GRUB back.